# convert word (doc, docx) to pdf in a c# web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, docx, doc

Is there any (easy) way to convert a doc or docx to pdf, server side? Any good/free libraries that can do it?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I tried with the office interop. But my server does not have word or office running and I don't want to be dependent of it.

Comment: This question appears to be answered [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/f8989c05-d04a-4b4a-be0f-fc0055691de7)

Comment: http://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/2009/10/converting-docx-into-doc-pdf-html.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do what I needed. I used OpenOffice service and combined it with a python command, python script, and an auto generated batch script. did the job perfectly and surprisingly quickly

Answer (score 2):

We use http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

It's not free and it doesn't handle floated elements very well, but it does the job.

It's pretty simple to use:

```
Document document = new Document(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName));

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // convert to PDF
    document.Save(ms, SaveFormat.Pdf);

    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was looking for a free library

Comment: Sorry, I took good/free to mean good or free. As in good/quick/cheap pick two :) I'm unaware of a solution that is good and free.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could install this free print driver: http://www.dopdf.com/

When you print to it, the output is a pdf file.

Comment: And how would the server side controller action code look like? Can doPDF be automated from .NET?

Comment: I checked and found the free version will not print without bringing up it's dialog box...so it can't be automated (with the free driver).